# Creating Controls Dynamically with JQuery .Clone() Method and then Accessing them on Button Click in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to create Controls of asp.net Dynamically. I have placed few checkboxes for controls like TextBox, Label, CheckBox and when these checkboxes are checked, a div is opened in which user can set the properties of these controls and Add multiple controls of that type on Button Click( with JQuery .Clone() method ). And at the last when user Clicks on "Create Form" Button than a new webForm opens and all that controls are displayed on it with the specified properties.

I am actually having trouble accessing these dynamically created controls.

```
mycontrol = FindControl("txttextboxText_0"+i);
```

In this line, I am getting the first control with ID "txtttextboxText_00" but i am not getting other controls with the IDs "txtttextboxText_01,txtttextboxText_02,txtttextboxText_03,...."

I am not getting that what I am doing wrong and where is the problem. Please guide.

Here is my code of JQuery.

```js
//duplicate divs

        var current_id = 0;
        var id = 0;
        $("#btn_atxt").click(function () {

            $('#textboxdiv').css({ height: '+=77' }, 500);

            id = current_id + 1;

            document.getElementById("hiddentxtcount").value = id+1;

            current_id = id;
            if (id < 10)
                id = "0" + id;

            var klon = $("#txtdiv_00").clone(true);
            klon.attr("id", "#txtdiv_" + id);
            klon.attr("name", "#txtdiv_" + id);

            klon.find("*[id]").each(function () {
                $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id").split("_")[0] + "_" + id);
                $(this).appendTo("#txtdiv_" + id);
            });

            klon.find("*[name]").each(function () {
                $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("name").split("_")[0] + "_" + id);
                $(this).appendTo("#txtdiv_" + id);
            });

            klon.appendTo("#d_txt").insertBefore("#btn_atxt");
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
  
</script>
```

and for c#,

```html
if (chk_txt.Checked == true)
                    {
                        Control mycontrol = new Control();
                        StaticControls.CreateTextBoxes(txtcount);
//For Dynamically Created TextBoxes..
//"txttextBoxText_00" is the TextBox in first Div
//Similarly "txttextBoxText_01" is the TextBox of dynamically created 2nd div with ".Clone()" Method

                        for (int i = 0; i < txtcount; i++)
                        {
                            mycontrol = FindControl("txttextboxText_0"+i);
                            TextBox temp1 = (TextBox)mycontrol;
                            if (mycontrol != null)
                            {
                                TextBox temp2 = new TextBox();
                                temp2.Enabled = Convert.ToBoolean(droptxtenable_00.SelectedItem.Text);
                                temp2.ReadOnly = Convert.ToBoolean(droptxtread_00.SelectedItem.Text);
                                temp2.Text = temp1.Text;
                                StaticControls.textBoxes[i] = temp2;
                            }
                        }
                        
                    }
```

Please let me know if you need anything else.
This is just a prototype. Let me know if I am using a wrong approach and what should be the best approach for doing this??
Thankx in advance.!